# How to put new placeholder resources into Android Studio project ("tools:sample" resources)?

Tags: android, android-studio

### Background

Sometimes, you wish to put some placeholders to be shown only on the IDE, in layout files.

As an example, you can use this:

```
<ImageView tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" ... />
```

And get this in the preview:

[image]

Such files are not part of the APK you get when you build your app, so it's safe to use just for developing.

This is what I was told from [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37127749#comment3):

> With sample data in 3.0, you can now have placeholder images that are
>   not part of the compiled apk. You just need a sampledata directory in
>   your project with a subdirectory containing all the images you want to
>   use as placeholders. You can refer those images from "tools"
>   attributes. Also, there are predefined stock images like
>   @sample/avatars or @sample/background/scenic

### The problem

I can't find how to add more of such images into the project (so that they will only be used in the IDE, and not a part of the APK), and if there is a way to put other resources, other than images.

In fact I can't find the docs of this feature.

### What I tried

I tried to put an image on "res/sampledata" and tried on "res/sample", but I wasn't able to reach it in both cases.

### The questions

1. What's even the name of this feature?
2. How can I put the image file into the project, and use it as a placeholder this way ? In which folder?
3. Is it possible to add more images to be used this way?
4. Is it possible to add other resources? Layouts? Strings?
5. Are there more capabilities of this new feature?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html. Does this help?

Comment: @Raghunandan I don't see it mentioned there.

Comment: like     `tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"` ? If i have `@sample/avatar` then error.

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes. This is the question. How to put more images into the project this way, to be shown on the IDE preview, yet the images won't really be a part of the APK. I want to know more about this feature.

Comment: hmm. my bad i understood it differently.

Comment: @Raghunandan Are you familiar with it though? How is it even called?

Comment: this is interesting. Its part of android studio.android-studi0/plugins/andorid/lib/sampledata

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> What's even the name of this feature?

Unconfirmed by an official source, but it's likely called "Sample Data".

> How can I put the image file into the project, and use it as a placeholder this way ? In which folder?

Unlike resources like images, fonts, etc. The sample data does not go in `/res/` (they are not compiled with the app, hence. It is probably easier to filter them out by putting them in a totally separate directory). They go in `/app/sampledata/`, for example: `/app/sampledata/image.png`.

You can create the sampledata folder by right clicking on app and do `New > Sample Data directory`:

[image]

You can then reference them like this, with `@sample/`

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    tools:src="@sample/test.png" />
```

While this does not give any errors, sadly the feature seems bugged right now, since the images do not show up in the preview, regardless of them being placed in a subdirectory or not (tried png, jpeg, jpg, xml).

Interestingly, placing a single image in a subdirectory and referring to that subdirectory instead of the specific image seems to work:

A structure of this

[image]

Combined with these references

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:background="@sample/image">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        tools:src="@sample/avatar" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        tools:src="@sample/jpeg" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        tools:src="@sample/vector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Produces this preview. Notice how I utilized `tools:background` to set the layout background to a sample image.

[image]

> Is it possible to add more images to be used this way?

Yeah, just add them to the folder.

> Is it possible to add other resources? Layouts? Strings?

It does not appear to support either. If you try to define some other type of resource, you either get a bunch of syntax errors due to keywords not being recognized, or you cannot refer to them with the `tools:src="@sample/` notation.

> Are there more capabilities of this new feature?

Unsure at this time.

Comment: Nice. How did you find this information? Just by trying?

Comment: @android A bit of trying and a bit of common sense

Comment: also the sampleData folder is found at android-studio/plugins/android/lib/sampleData. The avatars are all vector drawables and they are from 1 to 16. It just pics one. I made a small mistake by creating the sample directory in the root folder of the project rather than app so could not refer to the sample folder in xml

Comment: Will adding a VectorDrawable file (instead of normal image files) help ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper see edit, did some more testing. VectorDrawables (xml files) do not seem to work

Comment: It might be bugged. Perhaps we should wait for clarification on your google groups post

Comment: OK I put +1 for this answer, for the effort. Thank you

Comment: How do you add strings? Like those in "@tools:sample/date/day_of_week" ?

Comment: Which version of Android Studio is this using? I just get cannot resolve symbol for anything I try.

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer try building anyway. Recent versions of AS have a lot of  issues resolving symbols that are actually there

Comment: Thanks but I tried building and restarting AS and nothing shows still

Comment: There is nothing "common sense" about the whole Android development. Here I am trying what you have in AS3.2 and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Is there a way to reference these resources programmatically? Sure IDE preview passes some resource IDs via AttributeSet, but which ones?

Answer (score 7):

On my side I tried to use a image file as a placeholder for an Imageview using `tools:src="..."`: I did put my PNG file in a `sampledata`subdirectory but it either wouldn't show or appear as a broken image.

After a bit of fiddlings I found something that fixed my issue:

- create a `sampledata` subdirectory named: `drawable`
- place your png/jpg file in this directory and append the file name with "_drawable". Ex: `image.png` -> `image_drawable.png`

Only then did the placeholder showed up. 
You can create subdirectories from `drawable` as you see fit to keep your sample images organized, but the important thing seems to be that `drawable` remains a parent directory.

I do not have any documentation or sources to back me up, but I figure it could be useful for other in the same situation.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work using Android Studio 3.3. I just get cannot resolve symbol error

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer After adding the sample data restart Android studio

Comment: Are **svg** files supported for sample data?

Comment: how do you reference the sampledata? Studio only suggests `tools:src="@sample/drawable"` so the name of the folder. this results in an res not found image shown in preview

Answer (score 4):

I guess you have got the answer to other questions precisely by people who answered before me, but I can give you a workaround solution for particularly this question

> Is it possible to add more images to be used this way?

I have faced this problem for quite a bit of time and found a workaround for it.

My issue was that I couldn't use a `placeHolderImage` in a `SimpleDraweeView` which is a part of Fresco library of Facebook, if you didn't knew. But since an `ImageView` is not much complex like a `SimpleDraweeView`, and as the workaround worked with `SimpleDraweeView`, even though I haven't tried it with an `ImageView`, it might surely work with it too.

Here is the solution.

You just have to create a json file inside the sampledata folder, but this time, you have to do it this way.

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "image": "@drawable/ic_jam_jar"
        },
        {
          "image": "@drawable/ic_rice_bag"
        },
        {
          "image": "@drawable/store_avatar"
        },
        {
          "image": "@drawable/exclamation_icon"
        }
      ]
   }
```

As you can see, I have used the reference for `drawable` resource in place of value for `image` key. And it works in my case. What you get here in a way is an array of image resources which you can use inside the item of a `RecyclerView` to be previewed in **Design View** in Android Studio.

My RecyclerView code is as follows

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/product_desc_rec_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="350dp"
                        tools:itemCount="6"
                        app:spanCount="6"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/product_desc_item"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Remember not to skip any of the extra tags which I used, as it might not produce the required output in preview if you miss any. You can customize the `itemCount` attribute value according to your requirement of number of images you are using.
Also, `orientation` might be `vertical` or `horizontal` according to your use-case.

You can simply use `tools:src="@sample/your_json_file.json/data/image` inside your recyclerview item xml file's `ImageView` to load sample images there.

Try it and let me know if this works in your case or not.

Answer (score 3):

Tested with Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
(be patient with it, often it does not do immediately what you typed in...)

Following covers

- Drawables (both bitmaps and vectors)
- Strings

Directory/files structure:

```
<project workspace dir>
├───app  (=your module name, defaults to app)
    └───sampleData
        ├───drawable
        │   ├───some_name_drawable.png
        │   ├───some_othername_drawable.png
        │   └───some_3rdname_drawable.xml   // SVG vector
        ├───some_name.json                  // strings
        ├───some_other_name.json            // other strings
```

**Use of sample images**

```
<ImageView
   ...
   tools:src="@sample/drawable" />
```

**Important**

1. folder with images must be named "drawable"
2. file name of image/vector must end with "..._drawable.png" (.jpeg not tested) or "..._drawable.xml"

**Use of sample strings**

```
<TextView
   ...
   tools:text="@sample/some_name.json/data/something" />
<TextView
   ...
   tools:text="@sample/some_other_name.json/data/something_else"
<TextView
   ...
   tools:text="@sample/some_other_name.json/data/something_different"
```

where some_name.json contains:

```
{
  "data": [
    { "something":"Nice sample text" },
    { "something":"Nicer other text"  },
    { "something":"Awesome text" }
  ]
}
```

and some_other_name.json:

```
{
  "data": [
    { "something_else":"your text here" },
    { "something_else":"your text here" },
    { "something_else":"your text here" },
    { "something_different": "also here your text" },
    { "something_different": "also here your text" },
    { "something_different": "also here your text" }
  ]
}
```

**Important**

1. Android Studio requires the "data" as only root element in the .json file
2. Interesting and really nice: One .json file can have >1 sorts of strings

Comment: Interesting. You've added more information than the other answers, explaining about the multi-texts. How do you handle multi-drawables, though, like the "avatar" ?

Comment: I did not look into how to have different sorts of drawables as I had no need so far. If Google can out-of-the box have both "@tools:sample/avatars" and "@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" drawables, then I assume the same would be possible for user-defined sampleData as well. If Google would just document what they allow "behind the scenes", would help us all a lot... Above took me hours of try-n-error, and so I thought I share with the community to save someone else this effort...

Comment: Can you please try out about drawables?

Answer (score 2):

tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[5]"

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[5]"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```