# Why android doesn't allow any directory inside res folder?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to categories project images in different folders in `res/drawable/` folder but though on create new directory it does create new directory in project but it isn't visible and it also gives error on trying to build the project.

Comment: **`Android accepts only .png, .jpg, .gif and .xml files as drawable resources. `**

Comment: that's how google done it. There is nothing more to say about it. You can ask **them** why **they** did it.

Comment: So where should I categories images if I want so?

Comment: See this question by [paresh mayani](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4930398/996493)

Comment: @Prashant check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192545/how-to-put-new-placeholder-resources-into-android-studio-project-toolssample/46193419#46193419

Comment: Also check this [link](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-put-android-layout-files-in-subfolders-1f7cf07ff48f)

Comment: @Lucifer that was useful link, thanks.