# Why can't I use sample avatars in my app for display, other than tools?

Tags: android, imageview, sample

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
    android:src="sample/avatars"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

Comment: got any solution for this?

Comment: @NagendraHariKarthick not yet.

Comment: refer --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192545/how-to-put-new-placeholder-resources-into-android-studio-project-toolssample

Answer (score 0):

I guess since sample Avatars are not really drawable image assets. Hence, we can only render them on a tool setting (not built apk).